# MySQL query to list words containing user submited letters in order

Tags: php, mysql

I have this `MySQL` table containing a list of words:

```
desc words;
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id      | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| word    | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I also have a `HTML` form with three input fields where the user should enter three letters:

```
<form action='load.php' method='post'>
    <input type='text' name='first_letter'>
    <input type='text' name='second_letter'>
    <input type='text' name='third_letter'>

    <input type='submit' name='submit'>
</form>
```

Is it possible to create a `MySQL` query to fetch words containing the three letters in order of apperance, in the word?

For example if we have the words

```
adams
damn
mad
```

... and the user submits the letters "a", "d", "m" it should only give the result

```
adams
```

since the first submitted letter is "a", and the second submitted letter comes after "a" and so forth (even if there is other letters in between).

Or is it easier to sort the words using `PHP`? If so, how? I'm a beginner programmer.

Comment: Just to get an idea for the scope, how many words do you expect to have in your DB, how long are the words, and how many letters do you expect a user to submit?

Comment: About 120k words from 1 to ~30 characters

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well it won't be efficient by any means, but the following should get the job done:

```
$string = '%' . implode('%', $letters) . '%';
$query = "SELECT word FROM words WHERE word LIKE '$string'";
```

This will work regardless of if the letters have anything between them, as long as they appear in the correct order.  It also allows varying numbers of letters to be specified.

Edit:
`$letters` needs to be built for the query, too.  Specific to this example, it can be built like this:

```
$vars = array('first_letter', 'second_letter', 'third_letter');
foreach($vars as $var){
    if($_POST[$var]){
        $letters[] = $_POST[$var];
    }
}
```

If the `POST` variable names were changed to `letters[]`, the process could be simplified to this:

```
foreach($_POST['letters'] as $letter){
    if($letter){
        $letters[] = $letter;
    }
}
```

All of the data going into this should also be validated/escaped, but that is outside of the scope of this question.

Comment: Thank's, it seem's to do the work. Is it possible to filter the result a bit more to only populate the words starting with the first submitted letter? In my example list only the words starting with "a"

Comment: @David Yes, just remove the first `%` on the `$string` line.

Comment: Please excuse my lack of PHP knowledge but how does the `$letters` variable look like?

Comment: @David You'd need to build it.  I'm updating my answer now with an example.

Comment: **Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attack.**  You *really* should be using [prepared statements](http://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/623041), into which you pass your variables as parameters that do not get evaluated for SQL.  If you don't know what I'm talking about, or how to fix it, read the story of [Bobby Tables](http://stackoverflow.com/q/332365/623041).

Comment: @G-Nugget Thank you very much! Work's like a charm. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

A simple query would do it

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("select word from words where word like '%?%?%?%'");

$stmt->bind_param(
  'sss'
  , $first_letter
  , $second_letter
  , $third_letter
);

$stmt->execute();
```

**Update**: Using parameters instead

Comment: You can't have parameters inside a string literal.  To use parameters, your pattern would need to be the result of an expression that performs string concatenation within SQL, such as `WHERE word LIKE CONCAT_WS('%', '', :A, :B, :C, '')`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear how the user is "submitting the letters 'a', 'd', and 'm'" but the `LIKE` clause is the most common for this sort of [pattern matching](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/pattern-matching.html).

Try:

```
SELECT id, word
FROM words
WHERE word LIKE '%a%d%m%'
```

Comment: What the OP is looking for seems to be `LIKE '%a%d%m%'`.